# FFT frequency-magnitude not correct when a positive gain EQ point is applied

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, audio, impulse-response, magnitude

I have a measurement system, which applies a log sine sweep as stimulus to a DUT and records the return signal.

I then extract the impulse response, and perform an FFT on this to examing phase and magnitude in the frequency domain of the device. 
In this scenario, I have an audio interface connected to my computer, the output goes to an audio processor, where I have a single EQ filter, and the output back to my audio interface.

When I measure the device with no EQ inserted, I am given a flat response in both phase and magnitude.  If I give the EQ point negative gain, I see the filter as expected.  If I give the EQ positive gain, the phase looks correct, however the magnitude seems smeared over several bins.

Below is the measurement with the EQ point just above 1k.

[image]

Below is the same EQ point but boosted:
[image]

I have tried several measurements, including averaging across 3 measurements, and the result is the same, which leads me to think my methodology is incorrect.

1. I have the two audio signals. (one my original stimulus, and one the recorded return signal)
2. I get the impulse response by performing a forward FFT on each signal, then dividing the referenceFFT by the recordedFFT.  Finally I perform an inverse FFT to get back to the time domain, giving me my impulse.
3. To get the magnitudes, I window the impulse response, and then perform a forward FFT on this.  I then use:

$$\text{mag} = 20 \log_{10} \left(\sqrt{\Re^2 + \Im^2}\right)$$

for each complex result to give me my magnitude in dB.

Does anyone know why I cannot detect positive EQ correctly?  and if so, how I rectify this?

Comment: dunno what your EQ is.

Comment: I missed this,  The DUT is a processor which measures correctly using other applications.  The EQ filter is correct in the top screenshot,  a filter with a tight Q of 6, and gain of -20dB at 1050Hz.  In the second screenshot, all that has changed is the gain is now +20dB.  However as you can see, this measures a very wide filter that is nowehere near +20dB.  Other applications measure the correct version which should just be a gain inversion of the first screenshot filter.

Comment: How long is your sweep? The impulse response for this filter will be pretty long, so to avoid smearing, your sweep might need to be fairly slow.